# Monte Carlo Analysis in LTspice: Gaussian or Uniform distribution for the tolerance of resistors?

Tags: ltspice, signal-processing, tolerance, monte-carlo

I am running 1000 simulations in LTspice to do Monte Carlo Analysis of the output voltage signal on a circuit with 3% tolerance resistors.

Firstly, does LTspice assume the resistors' values are Gaussian distributed or uniformly distributed? How would I change that, if possible? Secondly, does it assume the tolerance are the extremes of the resistance value, or the standard deviation?

Comment: Se [this](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/how-to-model-statistical-tolerance-analysis.html). `mc()` is flat, you'll need `gauss()` for Gaussian.

Comment: Thank you very much! that was helpful!